# can I control the way a promise returned by a then() method resolves

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

Given I create `myPromise`.
It returns another `promise` when it resolves.

```
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('my promise resolved after 2 seconds');
     }, 2000);
})


myPromise.then(value => {
    console.log(value);
}).then((value) => {
    // how can I make the promise returned by myPromise.then() 
    //resolve in a specific way ?
})
```

How can I control the way the `promise` returned by `myPromise.then()` resolves ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The promise is already resolved when the `then` function is called.

Comment: Could you reformulate your question? It's pretty hard to understand the question

Comment: *return value* , passes value to the next then OR *return new Promise* awaits the new Promise and the next then is its result

Comment: In my answer, I gave an example of how to simply return the value, and how to return a new promise. Out of curiosity, which were you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a `.then()` handler, you have three choices that all influence the promise returned by that `.then()` call (I'll refer to it as the "parent" promise).

1. **Return a value.**   When you return a value from the `.then()` handler, that value becomes the resolved value of the promise that was returned when `.then()` was originally called.
2. **Return a promise.**  When you return a promise from the `.then()` handler, it is chained to the parent promise and the parent promise will "follow" the new promise (resolve/value, reject/reason).
3. **Throw an exception.** This will cause the parent promise to be rejected and the exception becomes the reject reason.

If you return nothing from the `.then()` handler that is the same as `return undefined` so it just sets the resolved value to `undefined` (same as returning a value of `undefined`).

---

This structure you show:

```
myPromise.then(value => {
    console.log(value);
}).then((value) => {
    // how can I make the promise returned by myPromise.then() 
    //resolve in a specific way ?
});
```

is troublesome because the first `.then()` handler returns nothing.  That is the same as returning `undefined` and thus the second `value` is always `undefined` and thus not useful.  If you had some actual reason for the first `.then()` handler, you could keep the desired value by returning it like this:

```
myPromise.then(value => {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
}).then((value) => {
    // how can I make the promise returned by myPromise.then() 
    //resolve in a specific way ?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do some other async operation, just return the value:

```
myPromise.then(value => {
    return value;
}).then((value) => {
    // ...
})
```

But I'm not sure why you'd do this, considering you could just remove the first `.then` and do everything in the second `.then`.

If you have to do another async operation, you can return a new promise and resolve it when you need to:

```
myPromise.then(value => {
    // Do some other async operation. I am explicitly creating the promise 
    // here inline to be clear. In real code, you'd probably want to wrap this 
    // in another function.
    return new Promise((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
        resolve(value);
    });
}).then((value) => {
    // ...
})
```

Comment: why not return value; ?

Comment: You can do that, but the question was already basically doing that using the second `.then`. So I assumed they wanted to do something else  async before it the second `.then`.

Comment: The second part is an antipattern. There's no need to create a new `Promise` at all.

Comment: @DanielB if a new async operation has to be done, like an http call, how else would you do it?

Comment: Write the function to return a new promise and call `.then(myOtherAsyncFunction)`. Value returned from the first call will be passed as argument to `myOtherAsyncFunction`.

Comment: So you're still returning a new promise. I'm just doing it inline. Often you'll see something like `return $.ajax...` inline.

Comment: Yes, because `$.ajax` returns a promise. You are explicitly constructing a new promise. I see a big difference between those two cases. One is considered an [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) while the other isn't.

Comment: My example was intentional. I am explicitly creating a new promise inline to be clear about what is happening. I didn't want to hide the new promise inside another function.

Comment: @DanielB I added a comment to clarify that in real code you'd want to wrap the promise.